# Translating a sentence containing によって

Tags: meaning, verbs, parsing

> 「今から家へ帰るところだけど、晩ご飯の買い物はもう
>   終わってる？」
>
> 「うん、さっきお母さんと電話で話したけど、スーパーによってから帰るって言ってたから、お母さんが買って帰るはずだよ。」

I understand the overall meaning of these sentences, but I'm rather confused about how I should translate によって in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> スーパーによってから帰る

スーパーに寄ってから帰る　*I'll get home after dropping in at the supermarket.*

Comment: Silvia: To clarify, it's not the grammatical によって here meaning "by" or "by means of," but the verb 寄る "to stop by."